# How can I validate if card has insufficient balance or card is declined in stripe payment using payment intent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-9, stripe-payment-intent

I have implemented stripe payment using Laravel. In which I am making payment using payment intent.
When I enter wrong card details, it shows me the error message at the time of creating the token. But when I try to make payment with cards like insufficient balance, lost card, blocked card, etc. from stripe test cards. It accepts payment from all cards instead of showing me the error message and shows me entry in my stripe account.

First I have created token, then created payment intent and then confirmed the payment intent.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow shams! i do curious, even expired card also pass? i'm not sure if this even a programming question. it feels more of stripe issue, best addressed by asking stripe's support.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @Tarzan Thanks for posting reply. I was able to fix it with the help of my co-worker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch.  In the catch you need to catch paymnet exception.  You will get exception list in the stripe documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).